# grunt-injector: Inject bootstrap bower component to index.html

Tags: gruntjs

I have done my research with grunt-injector. However, I have not found anything explains simply enough the process of injecting some file to another by grunt-injector.

My `index.html` header:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<title>SmartHome</title>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- build:css(client) styles/global.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/normalize.css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Everytime I run grunt serve, it would delete the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

I have no idea why. My `bower.json` has included bootstrap ~3.3.4 as a dependency. I've tried numerous methods with `bower install --dev` etc... But no luck to get this link back.

So I think my last resort would be to use the grunt-injector function. Can anyone gives me a hint with the syntax needed ? My files structure:

```
/client/
---bower_components/
    (somemore folders)
    ---bootstrap.css
index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you can use: https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep

Example:

```
wiredep: {

                  task: {

                    // Point to the files that should be updated when
                    // you run `grunt wiredep`
                    src: [
                      'src/main/resources/view.html'
                    ],

                    options: {
                      // See wiredep's configuration documentation for the options
                      // you may pass:

                      // https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#configuration
                    }
                  }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
injector: {
    options: {
        // Task-specific options go here. 
    },
    bower_dependencies: {
        files: {
            'index.html': ['bower.json'],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could improve your answer by explaining briefly what does your code do and why does it answer the OP's question